# header CSS for Iphone 5

Tags: css, responsive

I would like to adapt my screen for an iPhone 5

[image]

The size for an iPhone 5 is of ***320x568***

My problem is that the elements aren't on a line.

I have to reduce the font-size? The problem is that the screen is small enough.

[image]

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    /* Iphone 5 */ 
 
    .top-bar {
        position: relative;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve my problem currently.

Here is my code in HTML and CSS:

```css
/*******************************/
/********* General CSS *********/
/*******************************/



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1,
h2, 
h3, 
h4,
h5, 
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

/**********************************/
/********** Top Bar CSS ***********/
/**********************************/

.top-bar {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.top-bar .top-bar-left {
    display: flex;
}

.top-bar .text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 /* aligne les éléments sur la même ligne */
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-bar .text i {
    color: #C22312;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.top-bar .text h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-bar .top-bar-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-bar .hyper-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.top-bar .hyper-text i {
    color: black;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    /* Iphone 5 */ 
 
    .top-bar {
        position: relative;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        font-size: 15px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="top-bar">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
               <div class="text">
                  <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                  <h2>138 runnings days</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="text">
                  <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                  <h2>admin@superbtc.biz</h2>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
               <div class="hyper-text">
                  <select name="language" id="language-select">
                     <option value="english">English</option>
                     <option value="french">French</option>
                  </select>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>Deposit</a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>Paidout</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the design choice of what to do. You can make something smaller or hide something. The most popular approach is to have a separate menu on mobile (triggered by hamburger or similar). This menu, when opened, takes a lot of space, so you could put it there.

Comment: You can also help make your site more responsive by converting all of your values with pixels equivalent 'rem' value. Which will resize things to a small degree when the view port changes size.

Answer (score 1):

I love to use `vw` and `%` units in CSS for responsive web-design.
There's an easy way to make responsive font-size with `vw`:

```css
.back {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5vw 0;
}
.fore {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <span class="fore">Responsive.</span>
</div>
```

---

Here's a working example:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1,
h2, 
h3, 
h4,
h5, 
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

/**********************************/
/********** Top Bar CSS ***********/
/**********************************/

.top-bar {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.top-bar .top-bar-left {
    display: flex;
}

.top-bar .text {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
 /* aligne les éléments sur la même ligne */
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2vw !important;
}

.top-bar .text i {
    color: #C22312;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.top-bar .text h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-bar .top-bar-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-bar .hyper-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.top-bar .hyper-text i {
    color: black;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    /* Iphone 5 */ 
 
    .top-bar {
        position: relative;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        font-size: 15px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="top-bar">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
               <div class="text">
                  <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                  <h2>138 runnings days</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="text">
                  <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                  <h2>admin@superbtc.biz</h2>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
               <div class="hyper-text">
                  <select name="language" id="language-select">
                     <option value="english">English</option>
                     <option value="french">French</option>
                  </select>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>Deposit</a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>Paidout</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can make styles to elements if the browser/device is a specific width / height, with a CSS rule called "`@media`":

```css
p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #333;
  }
  p {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Resize the browser to see the effect.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

See more at https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_responsive.asp

Comment: It's usually a terrible idea to use viewport units for `font-size`. The only scenario where it makes sense is for font-based icons. You'll end up having a huge text on those wide screens.